# Phonegap iOS Change Threading Mode of sqlite

Tags: ios, cordova, sqlite

In iOS sqlite is defaultly compiled with Multi-thread Mode ( SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD ). I want to change the mode to Serialized. In Native project i can done this via

```
sqlite3_shutdown();
if (sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"sqlite configured to be threadsafe");
}
sqlite3_initialize();
```

But now i am working with a `phonegap` project. How can i achieve this using `javascript` code?

Answer (score 0):

This is no standard option in PhoneGap, you can solve this by creating a PhoneGap plugin.

Take a look at [Phonegap Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)